# Getting index for multiple selected item in ListBox in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, multiple-select

I have two ListBoxes. First `ListBox` items are list of "Products". and second `ListBox` items are list of "Item in Product" so When user click the item in first(Product) Listbox The second `ListBox` will show the list of items in selected Products.

eg:

```
Products     Items in Proucts
  AA*                 1
  BB                  2
  CC                  3
```

in example above current user selected AA products. And 1,2,3 are the items in product AA.

For the current program,i've done. User **only can select One "Products" at a time**. Then i want to **change to multipleselected.** So i want to get index number for each product that user selects, then i can retrieve data from database to get "Items In Products" for all selected products.

```
if (productsListBox.SelectedItmes.Count >= 0)
{
 // please provide me coding here to get index number for each selected items in   productListBox.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i already getting the answer:

```
 if (productListBox.SelectedItems.Count >= 0)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < productListBox.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
       {
            MessageBox.Show(productListBox.SelectedIndices[i].ToString());
       }
  }
```

Comment: SelectedIndices should be replaced by SelectedItems. Tried to suggest an edit, but the reviewer answered "This edit is incorrect". Go figure why.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (productsListBox.SelectedItmes.Count >= 0)
{

    string IDs = string.Empty;
    foreach( ListItem li in productsListBox.SelectedItmes ) 
    {
        IDs += li.Value+"," ;
    }
        IDs = IDs.Trim(',');

}
```

It'll give you a CSV of selected IDs

Comment: i do use VS 2005. look ListItem properties no support here.

Comment: There is ListViewItem :). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)

Comment: Ok. Actually you didn't mentioned web or windows here, I thought you were asking about web (asp.net).

Comment: Tried to edit for typos, but got rejected when I renamed SelectedItmes to SelectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string GetTagsList()
    {
        string Tags = string.Empty;

        if (lstTags.SelectedItems.Count >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstTags.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                Tags += lstTags.SelectedIndices[i].ToString() + ",";
            }
            Tags = Tags.Trim(',');
        }

        return Tags;
    }
```